# Split a list into separate words

Tags: python, pandas

he remove_non_apha variable is a list. Hence, you can't call str on it.

To split each item of the remove_non_apha list into individual words, do the following:

new_list = []

for each in remove_non_apha:
    new_list.append(each.split(" "))

Comment: you are using a list comprehension in the first line which returns you a list and not s string object. Could you post some text example that you are trying to work on and expected result?

Comment: Can please add some sample data for better answers?

Answer (score 0):

The `remove_non_apha` variable is a list. Hence, you can't call `str` on it.

To split each item of the `remove_non_apha` list into individual words, do the following:

```
new_list = []

for each in remove_non_apha:
    new_list.append(each.split(" "))
```

To count the occurrence of each word, you'll need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Hope this helps

In your first line of code, you need to understand that after this line executes the `remove_non_apha` data type will be a `list`

```
remove_non_apha = [re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ", file) for file in data[0]]
remove_non_apha.str.split(' ').str.len()
```

So you cannot use `.str.split(' ').str.len()` over it, which resulted you in `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'`